# communication between Web-UI Components

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I'm a rookie Dartisan. I've pushed test project on https://github.com/mackristof/DartWebComponentCommunication .
I want to find the best implementation for communication between 2 web components.If user click button on webComponent 1, how can counter webcomponent 2 can be informed ? Stream ? Bus-Event ?

Thxs for pull request with best solution.

Christophe.

Answer (score 1):

For this type of communication I have implemented an [event bus](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/event_bus), and it has been quite useful for me.

If the event bus is defined at the app level, your event can look something like this;

```dart
void increment() {
      eventBus.fire(clickEvent, 1)
}
```

And your counter component can be backed by a model object something like;

```dart
class CounterComponent extends WebComponent {

    int get count => viewModel.count;

    ViewModel viewModel;
}
```

and the ViewModel can look something like

```dart
class ViewModel{
    int count;

    ViewModel(){
        eventBus.on(clickEvent).listen((msg){
            count = count + msg;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think web components can talk to each other through the parent/host DOM using events. When one web component will trigger some event, host/parent DOM should catch it and inform the other web components by changing their attribute values.
This way I think web components can communicate.